# 3 instances of MapActivity

Tags: android, api, maps, instance

It states clearly in the Maps API that only one MapActivity per process is allowed.
My problem is i need 3, it's not necessarily 3 Activities but it is 3 instances.
I created a Travell agent app that allows you to book hotels and activities. focusing for a second in the hotels feature of my app, when you search hotels you can, naturally, see the all on the map, this is the first instance of the MapActivity i need, to show all hotels.
If you choose hotel either form the ListActivity or from the MapActivity you can see that hotel's info in HotelInfoActivity. the hotelInfoActivity also has reference to a MapActivity that lets you see that specific hotel on the map without any other hotels.... (next step would be to add routes to that as well, but that feature is not in development just yet).

The bugs happen when you do the following scenario:

1. you enter the map of all the hotels
2. you get into the hotel info
3. from the HotelInfoActivity you get into the MapActivity to see the hotel on the map ( I start the same activity but with intent with different data which is detected by my MapActivity).
4. till this point everything is ok.
5. i press on back twice (back to HotelInfoActivity,then back to MapActivity of All Hotels).
6. i see the previous (single hotel) MapActivity.

Is there is  any way around that issue ? it's great that i have two instances of the activity on the activities stack so i can navigate back to every instance, but how can i prevent them to pass states from one instance to another ????

(BTW the third instance is AFTER you've reserved the hotel you have the ability to see it on the map, but i don't have problems there for some reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there is any way around that issue ?

Only have one `MapActivity`, as the documentation states. You do not need more than one `MapActivity` for the scenario you have described. Change your overlays and map center/zoom levels based upon user interaction (e.g., icon taps and BACK button).

Comment: basically i let android do it for me, i have one MyMapActivity in the application. i do start it with intent that contain different values and for those different values the overlays are filled and added to the map.
my problem is when i resumed an already used MyMapActivity, it loads the previous map display even though that MyMapActivityInstance was destroyed with OnDestroy.
I'm now checking if moving some code on onResume instead of onCreate will solve my issue.

Comment: i'll accept the answer though it doesn't says anything new...
i have moved the code that adds the overlays and sets the zoom and map's center to the onResume function and that's solved my problem, the issue is the caching that MapAcitivy does to save network action that even though i resume an old instance the MapActivity takes the most recent tiles from the Activities store. bad behavior for google if you ask me...

Comment: @codeScriber: `MapActivity` has documented limits. You read the documentation, ignored it, and your code did not work as a result. If you do not wish to abide by the limitation, feel free to use an alternative mapping implementation (e.g., Open Street Map). Ideally, an application could have multiple `MapActivity` instances. Ideally, I'd have more hair. We do not live in an ideal world, to which my balding pate stands testament.

Comment: agreed, however i have a spec to to complete and using your method (meaning whenever i'm launching a map activity use SINGLE_TOP flag) i'll loose the activity in the activity stack (since it'll be brought to the front), so basically what u are stating that i cannot apply to my spec. u are right this is not a perfect world, never was but since google maps app does have that feature yeah i think it is their bad behavior, besides i have just one MapActivity, but multiple instances, and creating another process to host more then one instance is horrific in my opinion.